# Path effect for subplot title box using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Here is a figure I clipped from a published paper [here](https://ehp.niehs.nih.gov/wp-content/uploads/120/3/ehp.1103671.pdf)

[image]

I tried to mimic the plotting and failed to draw the subplot title **A**  with a shadowed box.

I have thought about one substituted solutions:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.subplot()
ax.text(0.1,0.55,'A',fontsize =14,transform=ax.transAxes,bbox=dict(boxstyle="square",ec = 'k',fc = '#FFFFFF') ) 
# Create a Rectangle patch
rect = patches.Rectangle((0.1,0.5),0.05,0.1,linewidth=1,edgecolor='k',facecolor='k')
# Add the patch to the Axes
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

[image]

However, the box is in a rectangular form. Any better method to reproduce the first figure? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem here? Both your figure and the original figure appear to have a rectangular box with a shadow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: better how? your solution seems reasonable, and produces the correct result.